# property in domain class not mapped to a table

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I want to add a property to a domain class in order to calculate something using the properties of the class:

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name="tablename")

 public class MyDomainClass {

    int id;
int property1;
int property2;


    @Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name="id")
public int getId() {
    return this.id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}


@Column(name="property1")
public int getProperty1() {
    return this.property1;
}
public void setProperty1(int property1) {
    this.property1= property1;
}



public int getProperty2() {
            ;doSomething
    return this.property2;
}
public void setProperty2(int property2) {
    this.property2= property2;
}
```

I don't want the property2 to be mapped to the table "tablename", but actually it is.

how could i fix it?

I need to access this property from jsp, e.g., domainclass.property2

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`@Transient`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Transient.html) annotation to specify that a property is not persistent:

```
@Transient
private int property2;
```